# Jquery Knockout - get element instance inside data-bind attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a `select` element where i bind the css class using Jquery Knockout.

I want to access the current element instance directly from `data-bind` attribute, without creating a property in the `ViewModel` (because i have many `select` elements which shares the same functionality)

Is this possible?

```
<select id="select1" data-bind="css: { 'no-value-selected': $item.val() == '' }">
    <option value="">[Select a value]</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

**EDIT**
Using ViewModel to achieve this (what i want to avoid)

```
function ViewModel() {
    this.select1HasNoValueSelected = ko.computed(function () {
        return $("#select1").val() == '';
    }, this);
};
var viewModel = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

<select id="select1" data-bind="css: { 'no-value-selected': select1HasNoValueSelected }">
```

Comment: Not 100% sure what you're asking here, could you explain your scenario a little better? To "access the current element instance" could be done via the DOM easily?

Comment: I have added an working example in my question..hope it's more clear

Comment: This is actually a pretty difficult one, I'll continue trying to crack it.

Comment: Yes..i know:) i did some research and didn't find anything. I used plain jquery to achieve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the wrong track with the `css` binding because if you are not using observables it won't update your class if the value of your select is changes.

However you can (miss)use the `event` binding and subscribe on the change event:

```
<select id="select1" class="no-value-selected" data-bind="event: { 'change': 
function() { $($element).val() == '' ? 
             $($element).addClass('no-value-selected') : 
             $($element).removeClass('no-value-selected') } }">
    <option value="">[Select a value]</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Wvfnu/) (second drop-down)

But the best solution is to not fight against KnockOut and have properties for each select on your view model:

```
function ViewModel() {    
    this.select1Value = ko.observable()
};

<select id="select1" data-bind="css: { 'no-value-selected': !select1Value() }, 
                                value: select1Value">
    <option value="">[Select a value]</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Demo [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Wvfnu/) (third drop-down)

Or don't use Kncokout for this function at all.

Comment: That's right..i was not using observables which would not trigger css value on value change. The second solution works perfect

Comment: You could use a custom binding, if you wanted a generic solution for all your selects.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use `$element` instead of `$item`:

```
<select data-bind="css: { 'no-value-selected': $element.val() == '' }">
    <option value="">[Select a value]</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
```

Docs: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html

Comment: Nope, $element is not defined